# How to retrieve object that I stored in azure service bus from message queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I stored object in azure service bus now I want to retrieve that object and its values. Here is my code that I used to store object in azure service bus.

```
class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
       {
foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\shubham.mittal\Desktop\xml", "*.xml")) 
            {
                string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(contents);
                string locationcode = doc.Root.Element("Customer").Element("Location_Code").Value;
                string Phone_Number = doc.Root.Element("Customer").Element("Phone_Number").Value;
                var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://namespacename.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sharedaccesskey";
                var queueName = "shubhamqueue";

                var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
                data d=new data();
                d.location_code=locationcode;
                d.Phone_Number = Phone_Number;
                var message1 = new BrokeredMessage(d);
                client.Send(message1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you have written is not enough to provide you with an answer. Please share the code you've written and tell us what issues you're facing.

Comment: Now I want to retrieve that object and  values that are stored in object

Comment: You included your shared access key in the question. Though I have edited the question and removed it but anyone can see this by going through edit history. Please change your shared access key ASAP.

Comment: Have you actually read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues#4-receive-messages-from-the-queue

Comment: I have changed my access key @GauravMantri

Comment: yes i have already read this article this return only string message when i changed this as object it is not returning any thing. @p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could get BrokerMessage info with [Brokered​Message.​Get​Body<​T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.getbody--1?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0). So in your case I create a demo and it works on my side.

1.Create a C# console project.

2.[Reference the Microsoft Azure Service Bus SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus)

3.Add a public Class

```
public class Data

{
    public string LocationCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

4. Add the following code to the main function in the Program.cs

```
  var client =
  QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("servicebus connection string", queueName);
  Data data = new Data
  {
      LocationCode =  "test location code",
      PhoneNumber = "test phone number"
  };
  var sendMessage = new BrokeredMessage(data);

  client.Send(sendMessage);

  client.OnMessage(message =>
  {
     var dataInfo = message.GetBody<Data>();
     Console.WriteLine($"location: {dataInfo.LocationCode}, phone number: {dataInfo.PhoneNumber}");
  });
```

5.Test the code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have already solved this problem and your code is same as of mine.

Comment: If it is helpful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities easily  to search.

Comment: if i am creating sending and receiving application separately then receiving part is not working it is not getting any data

Comment: It should work as expected. Please make sure that client are the same.

Comment: You also could create a new SO thread with detail info that cloud get more help from more communities.

Comment: Can anybody please state what is the equivalent process for retrieval when the message received is Message and not BrokeredMessage? Thanks